# How to align input on the lower edge label

Tags: html, css

How to align input on the lower edge label?

If the line is short, everything works fine, but if it is stretched and transferred to a new line, the input form remains at the level of the first line. I need the input form to be aligned on the bottom:

```css
.lbl {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
}

.inpt {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <label class="lbl" >yhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyh:</label>
 <input class="inpt"  type="text" >
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the floats from `.lbl` and `.inpt` the `input` will naturally sit inline with the last line of the `label`.

Im not sure why you are using `text-align: center` and then floating to the left, but to move the elements back over to the left, just remove `text-align: center` from the parent `div`.

```css
.lbl {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
}

.inpt {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
  <label class="lbl" >yhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyh:</label>
 <input class="inpt"  type="text" >
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox. `align-items: flex-end` on the parent element will put the input at the bottom of the div.

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.lbl {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
}
.inpt {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <label class="lbl" >yhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyhyh:</label>
 <input class="inpt"  type="text" >
</div>
</body>
```